# Comparing two string failing assertion

Tags: java, testng

This is really weird, im trying to assert two strings are equal and it's failing even though it looks to be the same.

```
    Assert.assertSame("Extra Spicy", type, "type is not extra spicy");
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: type is not extra spicy expected [Extra Spicy]
>   but found [Extra Spicy] 
>   Expected :Extra Spicy 
>   Actual :Extra Spicy

Everything matches, why is it failing?

Comment: Are you using JUnit?

Comment: I'm not too familiar outside the latest version of JUnit, but I believe the custom message argument,  "type is not extra spicy", should be the first. Is that right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Assert.assertSame` uses the `==` operator, which checks that two objects are the same object (have the same reference).

I think you want to use `Assert.assertEquals` which uses the `equals()` method, checking if the *value* of two objects are equal or not.

JUnit has some very helpful examples on their github:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assertions

Comment: thanks...for some reason i thought it worked the opposite way

Answer (score 0):

assertSame asserts that two objects refer to the same object. If they 
 are not the same an AssertionFailedError is thrown.

You can also check equality as follows

```
    Assert.assertEquals("Extra Spicy", "type is not extra spicy");
```